# Run a function when a ClientEmitter has an error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using an event handler, where each event code is in it's own files. I'm attaching the events to the client, so when that file has the event emitted, it will run that code:

```js
// looping through all event files
client.on(file.split('.')[0], require(`events/${file}`).bind(null, client, Util);
```

If the event file was `message.js`, it would be similar to:

```js
client.on('message', require('events/message.js').bind(null, client, Util);
```

So when the `message` event is emitted, it runs the `message.js` file, passing along the `client` and `Util` classes.

I also have a function that is attached to the `client` called `report`. It basically reports when there is an error. I would like it so whenever any event from the client has an error, it will run that function.
I've done this slightly with the commands: `command.run(...).catch(error => client.report(error))`.
Is there a similar way to do this, instead of having to put a try-catch around all code in all the event files?

Comment: Are you looking for `client.on('error', (error) => client.report(error));`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

```
client.on('error', require('events/report.js').bind(null, client, Util);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error handling should be context driven. This means your bot's response to the error should be dependent on what it was doing, in what channel, etc - both for debugging and for the end user's information on what happened. You'll miss out on all of the context by letting errors just travel all the way up into an uncaught exception, and without the ability to create an error message, the user will just see the bot not respond and think it's down or the command is broken.

My suggestion: Create helper methods for your most common error producing functions that wrap them with error handling. I did this mostly for sending messages, as there's a myriad of things that could cause a message send to fail out of your control and the handling consists of generating an error message and attempting to send it in the channel or DM it to the user if that fails.